# TT Norms font-face not rendering properly

Tags: css, rendering, font-face, issue-tracking

[image]

I have used TT Norms font-face but not rendering properly Please check 't' word. Please help

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Setting: “font-variant-ligatures: none;” works for me.

Answer (score 0):

font-variant-ligatures: none;

Its working fine for me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XUoo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPsX3.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).